# Why, after clicking the button "update State" the state inside the super doesnt update to sliced array instead console logs entire array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

In the given image below [image]

why, after clicking the updatestate button, doesnt update the state to sliced array that is  ['usa','china'] but instead updates to entire array in console.log, Yet on the page it shows it correctly.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 10 and 11 are called mutating states, which goes against React's recommended way to update the state, so it may or may not work.

Comment: so mutating states is not a way to go, got that part, so its like an anomaly that may or may not happen, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you use vue.js, line 10 and 11 are totally valid and recommended way to change state, but if you use react, you need to make sure you are not mutating the reference of `this.state.xxx`.

Comment: You can access `this.state.xxx` whatever you want, but not `this.state.xxx = yyy`.